# rebasing one commit vs merge --squash

Tags: git

If I have the following setup:

```
A--B  (master)
 \  
  C   (feature)
```

And I want to have changes made with `C` commit on master branch I have two options:

1. git rebase feature master
2. git merge feature master --squash &&
   git commit

Using any of them will produce the history for `master` branch like this:

```
 A--B--C'
```

So what's the biggest differences in both approaches given the initial setup?

Comment: You're looking at a degenerate case here.  Try the same experiment but on a branch with multiple commits.

Comment: With multiple commits I'll have different results, `git rebase` will create several commits, while `merge --squash && git commit` just one, I know that

Comment: Well, one big difference is that in approach #2, *you* are making a brand new commit, *now*.  In approach #1, the original commit information (author, date) is preserved.

Comment: If you rebase `feature` will point to `C'`, if you merge it won't.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, yeah, that's correct. No way I can change it using interactive rebasing?

Comment: @AndrewC, that is also correct, thanks!

Comment: You also could do a regular merge without squashing.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss, regular merge commit will produce a commit with parents, so the history will look different that rebasing or squash merging

Comment: @Maximus I know that, but you did not say anywhere in the question that this was a problem.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss, yeah, no problem, the question is indeed a bit vague)